# Point domain to subdomain folder with same url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a domain

```
http://www.example.biz/
```

I developed a site and put the code in a sub folder on this domain for example, the site is at

```
http://www.example.biz/site
```

now, I wanted to point my main domain to this folder so that when user visits `example.biz` he actually sees `example.biz/site` and for that, I added the below lines in .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /site/
```

it works perfectly however, the url user sees is

```
http://www.example.biz/site
```

I do not want that, I wanted user to only see `http://www.example.biz` as URL but this domain should point to the sub folder invisibly. How should I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simpler solution,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.biz$
RewriteRule !^site/ /site%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using mod_rewrite you can use the below rule, now when you access `http://www.example.biz` it will show the index file from for `site/`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /site/ [L]
```

Or if you want to show every file try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(/|.+)$ site/$1 [L]
```